# Diferenças entre o Facebook SDK e Google Play Game Services

Tags: android, facebook

Gostaria de alguma indicação, comentário, sobre ambas ferramentas para criação de jogos `Android` que busquem se conectar a redes sociais. A principal eu já sei, um conecta ao Facebook, outro ao usuário Google play e ao G+.

Mas queria mais informações para escolher um das ferramentas ou até utilizar ambas.

O jogo consiste em um Quiz, onde deve existir um ranking, as plataformas devem oferecer serviço para salvar o ultimo estado do jogo (fase) e scores totais e o jogador poderá publicar alguma informação na sua rede social. Estes são os principais requisitos.

Comment: Bem-vinda. Poderia elaborar um pouco mais suas dúvidas? Precisamos de perguntas que ofereçam respostas objetivas ou subjetivas bem embasadas: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective

Comment: Olá. Eu vi que você já aceitou a resposta que foi dada, mas apenas pra tentar colaborar eu gostaria de sugerir que você editasse sua pergunta pra colocar mais detalhes (talvez sobre o jogo ou sobre as motivações que você acredita que existem para ser necessária uma conexão social, etc). Sem mais detalhes, fica realmente difícil ajudar mais. :)

Comment: Apesar de eu a considerar subjetiva (não conhecia as regras), tentei explanar melhor minha dúvida. Não encontrei nenhuma informação dessa comparação em outros fóruns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que a maior diferença entre uma e outra seja o tipo de usuário que você quer atingir, e isso varias muito com o tipo de game que você pretende desenvolver. Google Play Games não tem todo o alcance que o facebook possui hoje, porem se o jogo vai rodar em um dispositivo com sistema operacional Android, é com certeza uma boa escolha ter uma integração com o Google Games e o G+, pois isso também gera ranking no google play store. Mas onde entra o facebook ai? Compartilhar a pontuação ou as badges na timeline do usuário? Acho que a pergunta ainda precisa ser mais específica.

Answer (score 0):

Eu acredito que, como será desenvolvido para Android, ambas podem ser utilizadas.

Mas, precisa-se entender que o facebook é apenas uma rede social, e não uma *library* para jogos. Logo, não é um objeto diretamente comparável às bibliotecas do Google, já que a última disponibiliza chamadas exclusivas para ranking, pontuação, etc.

Como você pretende utilizar as ferramentas de jogos, o G+ é imprescindível. Mas, isso não impede que os resultados e andamento não possa ser divulgado no Facebook.

Se você tiver que escolher entre uma delas. Vá de Google! Pode-se ter certeza que o usuário Android possui uma conta G+ cadastrada no *device*, o que ajudará a reter usuários.